# MSSQL - return column names and value if value is not NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In mssql, imagine I have a table with the following data...

```
id   name   monday   tuesday   wednesday   thursday   friday
1    mark    null    chores      null       gym        swim
2    steve   gym     null        class      hockey     null
3    mike    chores  gym         null       null       null
```

I would like to have a sql statement, that would return the id, name and day column where the value is not null, for example...

```
id    name    day        value
1     mark    tuesday    chores
1     mark    thursday   gym
1     mark    friday     swim
2     steve   monday     gym
2     steve   wednesday  class
2     steve   thursday   hockey
2     mike    monday     chores
2     mike    tuesday    gym
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should create table to save week days, and then do a relation between people -- days

Comment: select * from yourtable where value is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is `union all`, but I prefer `outer apply`:

```
select t.id, t.name, dayname, value
from t outer apply
     (values ('monday', monday),
             ('tuesday', tuesday),
             ('wednesday', wednesday),
             ('thursday', thursday),
             ('friday', friday),
             ('saturday', saturday),
             ('sunday', sunday)
     ) v(dayname, value)
where value is not null;
```

Comment: I tried this solution first, and it worked exactly as I wanted.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
select * from yourTable 
unpivot
(
day1 for value in (monday,   tuesday,   wednesday,   thursday,friday) 
) upt
```